# Replace table text in PowerPoint from Excel VBA, preserve PowerPoint formatting

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am attempting to replace the text within a PowerPoint table while preserving the existing PowerPoint table formatting.

Unfortunately, I have been able to find a way to do so. When I run the below code, all of the PowerPoint table text is reverted to size 14. I'd like to preserve the different text sizes within each of the tables, and even within each of the text elements (e.g., footnotes following certain text elements).

Please find my code below.

```
Sub UpdatePresentation()
Dim i As Long, FindWord As String, ReplaceWord As String, cell As Range
Dim path As String
Dim pres As String
Dim PPT As Object

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
path = "Dashboard Template.pptx"
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=path

For Each cell In wsDashboard.Range("E6:F35")
    If cell.Value2 <> "" Then
            FindWord = cell.Text

        ReplaceWord = cell.Offset(0, 2).Text
            
        
        Debug.Print (FindWord & " " & ReplaceWord)
        Call ReplacePresentationText(pres, FindWord, ReplaceWord)
    Else
        'do nothing
    
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Function ReplacePresentationText(ByRef PPTPres As Variant, ByVal FindWord As Variant, ByVal ReplaceWord As Variant) As Variant
Dim sld As Object, shp As Object, ShpText As Object, TempText As Object

    For Each sld In PPTPres.slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes            
            If shp.Hastable Then
                For i = 1 To shp.Table.Rows.Count
                    For j = 1 To shp.Table.Columns.Count
'                        shp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
'                    Replace(shp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, FindWord, ReplaceWord) ''USED THIS CODE TO REPLACE THE TEXT FIRST

                    shp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(p).Text = _
                    Replace(shp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(p).Text, FindWord, ReplaceWord)

                Next j
            Next i

            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing the .Text property, use the .Replace method on the text container, ex:

```
.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(x).Replace TextToReplace, TextToReplaceItWith
```